# Angular multi select set string array values does not work

Tags: angular, angular-forms

Angular multi select set string array values.

For update function want to set up multi select , selected values.

if we hard code values like this its working fine

```
controls["selectedT"].setValue(["QZEQ","QZYQ"]);
```

But when we are return values using DB that will not work.

Eg : `const sss = s;` // value = "QZEQ","QZYQ"

```
controls["selectedT"].setValue([sss ]);
```

Comment: this should work, try to assign value into global variable and access using `this.VARIABLE_NAME`

Comment: Is the variable `s` a string containing `"QZEQ","QZYQ"` or an array?

Comment: simply do like this `controls["selectedT"].setValue(sss.split(','));`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the spread(`...`) operator if you want to make it work with your current implementation:

Something like this:

```
controls["selectedT"].setValue([...sss]);
```

This will create another array on the fly and then assign it as the value of the `selectedT` control.

**OR**

you could simply do this:

```
controls["selectedT"].setValue(sss);
```

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multi-select-eg?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for your ref.